# How to use array as $_REQUEST in php

Tags: php

As we use `$sub = $_REQUEST["sub"]` for passing string onto the `php`
But How can I perform same thing in array
I want to pass String array as parameter onto the `php` file using `$_REQUEST`. 
Help me.

Answer (score 2):

Your question was unclear.

If you want `$sub` to array you can do:

```
$sub[] = $_REQUEST["sub"]
```

And if you want `$_REQUEST["sub"]` to array you can do:

```
$sub = $_REQUEST["sub[]"]
```